# Make DateTime::createFromFormat() return child class instead of parent

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3, extend, inheritance

I'm extending `DateTime` do add some useful methods and constants.

When using `new` to create a new object everything is fine but when using the static method `createFromFormat` it always returns the original `DateTime` object and of course none of the child methods are available.

I am using the following code to circumvent this issue. Is this the best approach?

```
namespace NoiseLabs\DateTime;

class DateTime extends \DateTime
{
    static public function createFromFormat($format, $time)
    {
        $ext_dt = new self();

        $ext_dt->setTimestamp(parent::createFromFormat($format, time)->getTimestamp());

        return $ext_dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for reviewing this, @lonesomeday.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the way to go. However, since what seems you want to do is to render the DateTime class extensible, I'd suggest you use `static` instead of `self`:

```
namespace NoiseLabs\DateTime;

class DateTime extends \DateTime
{
    static public function createFromFormat($format, $time)
    {
        $ext_dt = new static();
        $parent_dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);

        if (!$parent_dt) {
            return false;
        }

        $ext_dt->setTimestamp($parent_dt->getTimestamp());
        return $ext_dt;
    }
}
```

It's not necessary if you don't plan on extending the class, but if someone ever does, it will prevent him from having to do the same workaround again.

Comment: True, this is good practice, thanks for bringing `static` into the game. I was hoping to mimic `createFromFormat` and replace `self` with `static` but since `DateTime` is a C implementation I guess there is nothing else I can do, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine. An alternative way (just refactored a bit) is this:

```
public static function fromDateTime(DateTime $foo)
{
  return new static($foo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e')); 
}

public static function createFromFormat($f, $t, $tz)
{
  return static::fromDateTime(parent::createFromFormat($f, $t, $tz));
}
```

I'm not sure what the best way to implement the `fromDateTime` is. You could even take what you've got and put it in there. Just make sure not to lose the timezone.

Note that you could even implement `__callStatic` and use a bit of reflection to make it future proof.

Answer (score 1):

Previous solutions neglect time zones and microseconds, so my little improve is here.
I prefer variant 1, but in terms of performance 2 can be little faster on old PHPs.

```php
class NDateTimeImmutable extends \DateTimeImmutable
{
    public static function createFromFormat1($format, $time)
    {
        $parent = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);
        if (!$parent) {
            return false;
        }
        //Seting timezone like this and not by format to preserve timezone format
        $static = new static($parent->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'), $parent->getTimezone());
        return $static;
    }

    public static function createFromFormat2($format, $time)
    {
        $parent = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);
         if (!$parent) {
            return false;
        }
        $serialized = serialize($parent);
        // numbers can be computed by strlen() 
        // eg. strlen(parent::class) = 17 but it is slow
        $serialized = strtr($serialized, ['17:"'.parent::class => '18:"'.static::class]);
        return unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DateTimeEx extends DateTime
{
    static public function createFromFormat($format, $time, $object = null)
    {
        return new static(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time, $object)->format(DateTime::ATOM));
    }
}
```