# PHP: Subclassing DateTime and using createFromFormat()

Tags: php, datetime, static-methods

I have written my own class that extends `DateTime`. What I haven't been able to figure out override the static `createFromFormat()` so it returns an instance of my subclass. Is this even possible? Thanks!

---

[Joeren Offerjins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625231/jeroen-offerijns) gets the credit, but question is the same as mine, and has the answer I was looking for: [Make DateTime::createFromFormat() return child class instead of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450197/make-datetimecreatefromformat-return-child-class-instead-of-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Custom_DateTime extends DateTime
{
    static public function createFromFormat($format, $time)
    {
        return new static();
    }
}
```

I might be missing something here - why wouldn't this just work?

Comment: If I do this from that function: `return DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time);` - I will get a `DateTime` object, correct? Not my subclass?

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450197/make-datetimecreatefromformat-return-child-class-instead-of-parent

Comment: That other question was precisely what I was trying to ask. I will accept your answer.